# Redirect with header method after showing message

Tags: php

I want to show this message, then redirect to index.php after a few seconds.

```
echo "Se efectuó el borrado del alumno con dicho mail.";``
```

My problem is it automatically redirects to index.php, and I can't see the message.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Problema</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$conexion=mysql_connect("localhost","root","strlen12") or
  die("Problemas en la conexion");
mysql_select_db("base1",$conexion) or
  die("Problemas en la selección de la base de datos");
$sql="select codigo from alumnos
                        where mail='$_REQUEST[mail]'";
#echo $sql;
$registros=mysql_query($sql,$conexion) or
  die("Problemas en el select:".mysql_error());


if($reg=mysql_fetch_array($registros)){

   mysql_query("delete from alumnos where mail='$_REQUEST[mail]'",$conexion) or
    die("Problemas en el select:".mysql_error());
  echo "Se efectuó el borrado del alumno con dicho mail.";
  header('Location: index.php');
}
else{
    echo "No existe un alumno con ese mail.";
}
mysql_close($conexion);
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Could it be because you first echo, then redirect? Also use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for database connection.

Comment: I want the it show   echo "Se efectuó el borrado del alumno con dicho mail."; and then redirects to index.php in some seconds

Comment: Ok. How I do for show it in index.php.

Comment: If this is really a CakePHP question, you've managed to completely override the framework features :-?

Comment: If you want to show the text and redirect to index.php after a few seconds, check **napster3world**'s answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set a delay:

```
header( "Refresh:5; url=http://www.example.com/index.php");
```

so you can show the message and be redirected to the index after 5 seconds

Comment: don't forget you to check the best answer! ;)

Comment: @danielbarrera Please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you by clicking the check near the answer. Also please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), and [this FAQ question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is printing the message, but you are not able to see it as, it immediately redirects to `index.php` page.

If you want to show this message on `index.php` page. You need to `echo` this message there.

To display this message on `index.php`.

1) create a popup using Javascript or Jquery http://blazonry.com/javascript/windows.php and insert your message there.

2) Simply `echo` the message as you are doing on your existing page.

EDIT: I wont recommend it. But a quick fix to your problem in addition to Napster's answer.

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Really annoying pop-up!');</script>";
```

And if you want fancy stuff for your website, like displaying a loading gif or message. I would say just see this small tutorial. It might help you in future also. "http://banagale.com/display-a-simple-loading-message-and-animated-loading-gif-using-javascript.htm" :)

Comment: Yeah it would be nice, I misunderstood the question too. OP wants to show the message for a few secs, then redirect. But nice:)

Comment: Ankit If I want to show this message inside of a Div in index.php. Should I use AJAX?. I don't want to use a popup but a div

Comment: you dont need AJAX for this. As your message is fixed and is not changing. You can just put a `alert("Your message");` on `document.start()`